# How to set up git in RasberryPi3 ?

Tags: git, cron, raspberry-pi3

I'm having trouble setting up git in RasberryPi3. The purpose is to update RasberryPi's application with gits cron. Are there some tutorial or some examples for noobs like me to understand ? I would like to hear from you!

Comment: If you're using Raspbian it should be easy. Just run `sudo apt-get install git`.

Comment: Thank you. Im also wondering, how will I be able to run a git cron automatically for rasberryPi?

Comment: [This](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) explains setting up a cron job pretty well, and the Git man page is a good place to get any information on using Git.

Comment: A couple places you seem to be referring to cron as a component of git.  That is incorrect; you might find better information if you revise your searches accordingly